# How i use git push on a new remote branch?

Tags: git, push, branch, remote-access

I had a first master branch created by default.

I checkout a new branch called 'prd', and i want it to push to remote origin, but a on new branch.

I tried to do :

```
$ git push -u origin/prd prd
```

But the console logged  :

```
fatal: 'origin/prd' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Can somebody help me with this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-u` flag is short for `-set-upstream` and it expects a repository name. In this case the repository has an alias `origin`. The second argument is the name of the branch.

```
$ git push origin prd
```

Comment: Even without `-u` this would still be `git push origin prd`. That is, it's not `-u` that expects a repository name, it's *any* `git push` that expects one. More specifically, `origin` is a *remote*, which is a short name under which Git saves a URL.

Answer (score 9):

```
# Create a new branch:
git checkout -b branch_name
# Edit, add and commit your files.
# Push your branch to the remote repository:
git push -u origin branch_name
```

this should work.

Comment: Meanwhile I created the remote branch in github's GUI. Does it work without creating it on GUI?

Comment: git checkout -b branch_name should create the branch on its own. 
try this link it has some of the basics. https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches